# What does each of the color palette entries change the color of?

Tags: linux, terminal, colors

I've been editing my color profile and experimenting with what each entry changes the color of.

For reference this is what I'm talking about:

[image]

I've looked everywhere for a list of what each color palette entry changes the color for, but ended up empty handed

This is what I know so far for each "Palette entry #":

- 1 highlight color
- 2 String color
- 3 ? color of a certain highlight
- 4 ? python 'def' and 'TODO' color
- 5 ? Commented code, color of text when highlighted by "color palette 3"
- 6 ? imports/ escaped characters
- 7 ? function color main, print
- 8 ?
- 9 ?
- 10 color of text under a certain highlight
- 11 ? run-able file / executable / zip files
- 12 ?
- 13 Directory color
- 14 ? PNG files, pictures
- 15 ?
- 16 ?

Is what I have so far correct? What do the other entries change the color of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works the other way around. The terminal emulator *offers* 2*8 colors for applications to choose from, in addition to the default foreground/background colors, and doesn't know / doesn't care how applications use them. (There are much more colors available for applications, but these are the standard ones, and the ones typically customized by the user.)

These colors are traditionally black, red, green, yellow (brown), blue, magenta, cyan, white (light gray) and their brighter counterpart. You can pick your exact favorite shade for them, there are a few predefined ones, but you can also create your own scheme (and of course no one forces you to actually pick colors that are similar to the usual values and correspond to the formal names, just as you did for the first color (white instead of black) (*), likely resulting in hardly readable look in several apps).

Each application decides on its own which colors it wants to use for which feature, context etc. You need to consult the documentation and settings of each application where you're interested in its use of colors.

For example, for the `ls` command check the environment variable `LS_COLORS`. You'll recognize the file extensions, plus there are two-letter keywords for file types. As for the values, 30–37 denote the first 8 colors as foreground ones; 90–97, or often 30–37 combined with 1 (or 01) denote the next 8 colors as foreground ones – although 1 (or 01) also makes the text bold. 40–47 stand for the first 8 colors and 100–107 for the next 8 colors as background ones. For `mc` (Midnight Commander) the definitions are in the skin files under `/usr/share/mc/skins` or a similar directory, and for its editor the syntax highlight files in the `syntax` directory next to it. And so on... For every single application you have to individually check which colors it uses for what purpose, and whether (and if so, how) they allow to configure them. There's no common pattern or typical assignment of colors.

(*) There used to be a bug in gnome-terminal where the first color wasn't properly initialized on the UI, so perhaps it wasn't you changing it to white. This was fixed in gnome-terminal 3.20.3.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers listed point to palette colors (see **ctlseqs.txt** file) as @egmont
indicated, but the descriptions next to the numbers, such as Directory color, are
evidence of color setup for ls utility [see **dircolors(1)** & **dir_colors(5)**]. To see
the format, execute "`more /etc/DIR_COLORS`". To create a personal file, execute
"`dircolors --print-database >~/.local/MyLocal/.MyGNUDircolors.txt`" (no need to
clutter HOME). To invoke this file, code such as

```
if [ -f /etc/DIR_COLORS ] && [ "$TERM" == "linux" ]; then
  _colorfile=/etc/DIR_COLORS
  test -r $_colorfile && eval "$(dircolors $_colorfile)"
else
  _colorfile=/home/??USER??/.local/MyLocal/.MyGNUDircolors.txt
  test -r $_colorfile && eval "$(dircolors $_colorfile)"
fi
```

needs to be placed in .bashrc (change ??USER??).
When modifying the file, follow the instructions in **dir_colors(5)**. The following
are some of my entries:

> LEFTCODE \e[0;0;0 # Default: \e[
> RIGHTCODE m    # Default
> ENDCODE \e[0;48;2;139;095;101m\e[K # LightPink4
> FILE 3;39;48;2;139;069;019 # Italicize; Lt White/SaddleBrown
> # Bold; Double-underline; blue4 over burlywood
> DIR 1;21;38;2;000;000;139;48;2;222;184;135 # directory
> EXEC 4;38;2;124;252;000;40 # Underlined LawnGreen

NOTE: the ENDCODE may bleed into your prompt. I use a prompt that covers the
whole prompt line; it newlines so that a single colored $ is the actual prompt.
An example is the 2nd PS1 below. Why ENDCODE? No matter the terminal FG/BG colors - white on black, green on black, etc - there was always a loss of contrast: LightPink4 works for me.
The statement "editing my color profile" above the Preferences->Profile->Color
attachment leads to a different inference. At Color Palette, the 1st line
palette is 30/40 ... 37/47 & the 2nd line is 90/100 etc. All appears to be the default except for 30/40 (white). Put the following into a bash script:

```
# filename: ColorPalette.sh
echo -e "\e[0m\e[0;91;46mUse the following color reference as aid in color design:\e[0m"
echo -e "\e[0m\e[30m  0/30 \e[31m  1/31 \e[32m  2/32 \e[33m  3/33 \e[34m  4/34 \e[35m  5/35 \e[36m  6/36 \e[37m  7/37\e[0m"
echo -e "\e[0m\e[40m   40  \e[41m   41  \e[42m   42  \e[43m   43  \e[44m   44  \e[45m   45  \e[46m   46  \e[47m   47  \e[0m"
echo -e "\e[0m\e[90m  8/90 \e[91m  9/91 \e[92m 10/92 \e[93m 11/93 \e[94m 12/94 \e[95m 13/95 \e[96m 14/96 \e[97m 15/97\e[0m"
echo -e "\e[0m\e[100m  100  \e[101m  101  \e[102m  102  \e[103m  103  \e[104m  104  \e[105m  105  \e[106m  106  \e[107m  107  \e[0m"
```

The output will match the gnome-terminal Color Palette.
Put the following resource file into ~/.local/MyLocal/ (again,
avoid clutter) & execute the options indicated. Search the net with "color
codes for named colors" keeping in mind that numerous colors exist between named colors. Choose colors & replace below, then run ColorPalette.sh
until you're satisfied. Try selecting text & take note of text cursor color. Eventually, place the above conditional into the resource file & test with "`ls --color`". Line starting with #??, truncated version, is more efficient. Remove "#??" & comment the other lines.

```
# filename: .bashrcColorsTest
# In gnome-terminal, run "source ~/.local/MyLocal/.bashrcColorsTest"
#  ...or...
# use a different profile with Custom Command set to
# bash --rcfile ~/.local/MyLocal/.bashrcColorsTest
#  ...or...
# gnome-terminal --title "Color Test" -- bash --rcfile ~/.local/MyLocal/.bashrcColorsTest &
# to demonstrate.
#??echo -en "\e]10;orange\007\e]11;gray7\007\e]4;8;#4C43A2;15;olive;\007"
# Change OSC FG/BG colors. Using BEL (bell) form.
echo -en "\e]10;grey0\007\e]11;#808080\007"
# Change OSC text cursor color. Using ST (string terminator) form.
echo -en '\e]12;khaki3\e\\'
# Change OSC FG/BG pointer (mouse) colors.
echo -en "\e]13;red\007\e]14;blue\007"
# Set color0 (30/40)                 color8 (90/100).
echo -en "\e]4;0;#000000\007"; echo -en "\e]4;8;#545454\007"
# Set color1 (31/41)                 color9 (91/101).
echo -en "\e]4;1;#ff5555\007"; echo -en "\e]4;9;#ff5454\007"
# Set color2 (32/42)                 color10 (92/102).
echo -en "\e]4;2;#fa0074\007"; echo -en "\e]4;10;#50fa7b\007"
# Set color3 (33/43)                 color11 (93/103).
echo -en "\e]4;3;#7f0a1f\007"; echo -en "\e]4;11;#f0fa8b\007"
# Set color4 (34/44)                 color12 (94/104).
echo -en "\e]4;4;#3282ff\007"; echo -en "\e]4;12;#1200f8\007"
# Set color5 (35/45)                 color13 (95/105).
echo -en "\e]4;5;#1b3cff\007"; echo -en "\e]4;13;#ff78c5\007"
# Set color6 (36/46)                 color14 (96/106).
echo -en "\e]4;6;DarkBlue\007"; echo -en "\e]4;14;#8ae9fc\007"
# Set color7 (37/47)                 color15 (97/107).
echo -en "\e]4;7;#bbbbbb\e\\"; echo -en "\e]4;15;#ffffff\007"
# Change OSC selection FG/BG. Default is reverse video.
echo -en "\e]19;orange\007\e]17;black\007"
PS1=$'\[\e[97;100m\]\s-\V on `uname -s -r` \$\[\e[0m\] '
#PS1=$'\[\e[97;100m\e[K\]\s-\V on `uname -s -r`\[\e[0m\]\n\[\e[31;40m\]\$\[\e[0m\] '
```